# How to get the style properties of the variable in which you are storing text

Tags: javascript, css

tag for text area used

```
<textarea id="tag_text"></textarea>
```

I am using the following code to store the the content of text area.

```
var texAreaContent = document.getElementById("tag_text");
```

Now what code should I use to retrieve the **style** of **every word** of the text area content. Please provide the code in JavaScript and please provide a better way if you know because I am at a beginner level

Comment: What do you mean "the style of every word" in a text area? The content of an HTML text area *does not have styles*, it is only pure text. The only way the content of a text area would have styles is if they are applied with wrapping `span` elements to selectively apply them.

Comment: I guess you are looking for editors. But just to be clear - what do you mean by style of every word? Can you please give a little more clarity on what you want to type in textarea and exactly what you want to retrieve.

Comment: Words in textarea can't have style attached to them. Can you rephrase the question so it becomes clear what is you problem? You can get style of textarea element like this: textAreaContent.getAttribute("style").

Comment: @UrosK maybe he has multiple colors in text area. so he want to return every style property of that particular text

Comment: Yes @Mahi I want to retrieve the content's style for example if it is italic then on th basis of it some code will be executed if font size is less than 12px something else will be done. Do you know how this can be achieved

Comment: @KaranParikh you should use jquery its easy .
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_css_getcolor

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get what's your problem. 
i tried this in my way of understanding of your problem. Check this.

```js
var texAreaContent = document.getElementById("tag_text");

texAreaContent.style.color="blue";
```

```html
<textarea id="tag_text">Test</textarea>
```

Comment: maybe he has multiple colors in text area. so he want to return every style property of that particular text

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can do this like this

```
$("element").prop('tag_name')
```

You can change style of an element like this

```
$("element").css('background', 'lime')
```